# Showing all nested models in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and I'm teaching myself how to use it by working on my own project.

I have a model called Users that has a one-to-many relationship with a model called Pets. The Pets model has a belongs_to relationship to User. I'm trying to build a page where a user can see the list of all Pets. How can I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: Should the user see his own pets or everybody's pets?

Comment: I meant everyone's pets. Sorry.

Comment: Please show us what you've done, your question is too broad. If you've not done anything yet, maybe you should go learn with a [good tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)

Comment: Also, "nested models" are different. Nested models are where you want to create records or update the attributes of a child model from a parent model, using a form, and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tamer Shlash. It sounds like you'd benefit from practicing a tutorial to get more exposure to model-view-controller (MVC) concepts, and interacting with a database.

Since you want all users to see all pets, `Pet.all` will return all rows of the pets table.

In a controller action, assign `@pets` to `Pet.all` then use that instance variable to loop through the pets and display information about them.

```
<ul>
<%= @pets.each do |pet| %>
  <li><%= pet.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best looking at the R[ails getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to see how to do this properly. Basically, everything you want to achieve in Rails is done using the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - each `view` takes data from the `controller`, which builds that data from its `models`

Here is a basic example for you:

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/pet.rb
Class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pets
end
```

--

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pets #-> /pets
```

--

**Controllers**

```
#app/controllers/pets_controller.rb
def index
   @pets = Pet.all
end
```

--

**Views**

```
#app/views/pets/index.html.erb
<% @pets.each do |pet| %>
    <%= pet.name %>
<% end %>
```